# playready silverlight get license fails when url is about 400 chars long

Tags: silverlight, drm, playready

Like the title says I try to do a get license request and when my URL reaches above 400 chars it seems that no request is actually sent.
Anybody notice this as well?
Is there a way around it except shortening my URL?